# Why does someone work in a non-STEM field after completing a PhD in STEM?

Tags: phd, career-path, stem

Several years ago, when I was taking an English language course, one of my teachers said that one of her acquaintances did a Ph.D. in Biomedical Engineering and became a Headmaster in a Bilingual school.

At that time, I didn't think much about that information. However, since, I am preparing for a Ph.D. entrance, this question has become a sticking point in my mind. However, there is no way I can find this particular teacher and ask the question.

**Why might someone work in a non-STEM field after completing a Ph.D. in STEM?**

Let us define a STEM position as a position in which using STEM knowledge is the *primary* job responsibility.

For example, A Biomedical Engineer (BME) working as an entrepreneur in a biomedical engineering firm can be considered a STEM job. A Biomedical BME working as a teacher to teach Biomedical engineering is a STEM job. However, the same person working as an office administrator at the same department in the same college is not a STEM job, let alone working as a receptionist, etc. Also, a BME working as a patent lawyer **is** a STEM job.

Comment: Yes, this happens all the time for a myriad of factors and the emotions the individuals feel towards having completed their doctorate fall all over the spectrum from positive to negative. Bottom line: a STEM PhD doesn't guarantee you a job in your field, nor does it guarantee you will desire that future for yourself. Prepare accordingly for this lack of guarantees.

Comment: Because they liked it better?

Comment: Indeed this is a mysterious phenomenon. Here’s [another example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayim_Bialik).

Comment: Here another example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkel

Comment: I think the top answer makes a good point that answers will depend on your definition of "STEM field." I tried to summarize your position in the question; feel free to revise if I botched anything.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX, Okay. After knowing what a Patent Attorney is, I retracted my old comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I have to admit that I do not quite understand where exactly OP draws the line between STEM jobs and non-STEM jobs, and why. Since the comments may vanish, to sum up their position:

STEM:

- chemist working in archeology or museum/art restauration
- teacher, e.g. physicist teaching physics
- patent lawyer

non-STEM according to OP

- someone working in goods logistics where they apply the optimization techniques from their STEM profession
- business consulting by an engineer about product lifecycles

---

Some points that have not been mentioned so far:

#### STEM teachers

Well, even bilingual schools need STEM teachers!? And teachers are the population that headmasters usually come from.

- I also know physics PhDs who became teachers. Guess what subjects? Physics and math...
- When I was in school, we had a few teachers with PhD. My recollection is that at least from grade ≈10 - 13 one did realize that they had a substantially better knowledge of their fields than the average teacher.  Which does not say that there weren't also good and knowledgeable teachers without PhD. But it does say why a school may consider someone with PhD suitable as teacher.
- Where I am, STEM teachers are particularly scarce. It may be easer to hire someone from a STEM field (possibly with academic teaching experience) and train them to become teacher than to tell a non-STEM teacher to learn, say,  physics or chemistry.
  There have been state programs here that hire in particular STEM people
  and give them pedagocical training to become teachers.
- Side thought: the headmaster's office back then did a lot of what I'd nowadays describe as solving optimization tasks with lots of boundary conditions.
- BTW, where I am, headmasters usually continue to teach.

#### STEM work in non-STEM fields

There are large numbers of STEM people working in non-STEM fields (with e.g. the department on their business address not hinting at them being STEM) *in their original profession*.

- Many non-STEM fields need e.g. statisticians, engineers, etc.
- A chemist may work in a museum *as chemist* (e.g. analyzing paints or glues so that objects can be properly restored) or in archeology (working on questions like possible falsification/fraud detection of artifacts, what paints/technologies were used etc.).
- Patent lawyers: according to OPs comment non-STEM. Under that definition, every [German patent lawyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_attorney#Germany)) is a STEM professional who left for a non-STEM field (and the [German Wikipeda page says most of them did a [STEM] PhD before starting the legal training](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patentanwalt_(Deutschland)#Wege_zur_Zulassung)): over here, a full university degree in either a natural science or engineering (plus working experience) is prerequisite for the training to become patent lawyer.
  *(did later on become an "upgrade" to be considered STEM work)*

#### Problem solving and analytical thinking skills

Doing a PhD gives not only professional experience in one's field, but also in certain ways of problem solving, analytical thinking etc.

These particular skills of a STEM PhD are useful in many other jobs as well. It may be labeled a non-STEM field, but it is really something closely connected to their profession.

---

#### Management

Someone starting to work in their STEM profession may drift more and more into management. This even happens inside academia: many of the group leaders/professors basically do management and administrative jobs (professors have to do a minimum amount of teaching, though) and do not have time to do research themselves. Similar carreers happen in industry.
For the question at hand, the answer would then depend on whether we consider someone who's sitting in an office, doing lots of administrative work, grant writing and management (of STEM people) as STEM or not.
IMHO: not that much of a difference to the "STEM fraction" of the BME entrepreneur's work, or the patent lawyer's.

Comment: *STEM work in non-STEM fields* --- the examples are incorrect. These are not non-STEM jobs.

Comment: @user366312: whether you consider this STEM job or not is a matter of definition: "Dr. X, dept. of restauration, Arts Museum" does not hint more at a STEM job than "Dr. Y, teacher, BiLingual School" you may say that are non-STEM jobs. At the same time, if X does chemistry and Y teaches maths, you may say they both still work in STEM. So then does someone who actually does e.g. optimizations for goods logistics or business consulting where they apply their engineering background e.g. to product lifecycles. BTW, would you consider a patent lawyer STEM or not?

Comment: *So then does someone who actually does e.g. optimizations for goods logistics or business consulting where they apply their engineering background e.g. to product lifecycles.* --- This is also a non-STEM job.

Comment: *teacher, e.g. physicist teaching physics* --- this is not true. A CS graduate teaching CS should be a STEM job. Coz, he is using his CS knowledge to earn his living.

Comment: @user366312 but then what's the point of your question? I mean, at least over here, also headmasters usually teach. A biomedical engineer would likely be considered to have the subject-specific qualification to teach some of the following (depending on the specializations they took) subjects: biology, chemistry, maths, shop class plus there are "rare" subjects which schools offer only if they have a qualified teacher, e.g I once had an electronics course. Except the "skills" section, all examples I give "use their STEM-field knowledge to earn their living".

Comment: *A biomedical engineer would likely be considered to have the subject-specific qualification to teach some of the following (depending on the specializations they took) subjects: biology, chemistry, maths, shop class* --- However, she is not being able to use her highly specialized knowledge. So, that's a bummer.

Comment: @user366312: I don't think for any of the school teachers, more than undergrad subject knowledge is required. So that's true for the CS teacher and the physics teacher as well. But then, also within STEM people migrate from one field into another over time. I know a microbiologist, who then went on to (medical) statistics, and is now head of a chemical wet lab. A biologist who, via photochemistry research, now does chemical analysis and statistics. IMHO, the highly specialized subject-specific knowledge of a PhD is only one part of their specialization. The skills are equally important.

Comment: In the end, the PhD is only one project (typcially the first one of > 1a "size"). Over a professional life, there may be many, and easily several that require mastering new subjects at similar depth.

Answer (score 4):

There are several potential reasons, some of them coming together at the same time.

Earning a doctorate takes a while, longer in some places than others. People's desires might change over that time period and yet they complete the degree since they have invested a lot in to it and it offers an opportunity.

For some an unexpected opportunity arises near the end of the degree program and it seems to them at that moment to be preferable to continuing in STEM.

For some, an industry position might draw on their knowledge of some STEM field but not be directly connected to it. Management of a product development group in an industry is a possibility.

And, for some, the marketplace for their skills just collapses at the end of their student days. Again, time is a factor and the economics changes. It is a particularly hard time at the moment to obtain an academic position in many fields.

I'm sure thee are other possibilities. Some even return to a family business after earning a degree.

I know of one person who has an undergraduate (not doctorate) degree in CS and who is an excellent crime fiction writer. I await his latest book each year. And I don't actually recall CS being part of any of his books. But, he "scratched an itch" at an earlier point in his life.

Answer (score 4):

The most common reason is that management jobs pay better than STEM jobs.

Answer (score 3):

*Why did Ronald Reagan move into politics after being a film-star?  Why did Martha Steward move from modelling into stockbrocking, into homemaking?  Why did Terry Crews leave the NFL to go into acting?*

The answer in all these cases, is that people often have diverse interests, and they may be attracted to another field even after receiving training and experience in a different field.  Sometimes there is a symbiosis between the fields, because they require similar skills or characteristics, but sometimes there is quite a disparity.  You will find many instances where a person trains in a field, and maybe even works in a field for a substantial time, before transferring to a different field (some examples [here](https://www.businessinsider.com/successful-people-who-made-a-big-career-change-2016-4?r=AU&IR=T)).  Doctoral level education can open up some doors, but it is not a career-prison-sentence --- if you do a PhD in a field, it does not oblige you to practice in that field for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 2):

In part it is because multidisciplinary activities are all the rage, especially as of late. Sometimes people stay in STEM and change the field, sometimes they go to non-STEM to notice some problems that are trivial to them but pretty much nobody else around. So it is a low-hanging fruit, and people would often feel more appreciated and accomplished for picking it instead of banging their head on a wall at the forefront of research.

Comment: Hmm... That could be one of the points.

Comment: Yes, several of my PhD students (in "pure math..." with high technical prerequisites), who've not stayed in academic math, have said that "everything else is super easy" by comparison. :)